# Grails -Custom Sorting with associated domain class

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have domain

**Training**

```
class Training {

       static belongsTo = [venue: Venue]
 }
```

**Venue**

```
  class Venue {
        static belongsTo = [city: City]
  }
```

**City**

```
 class City {
  String name
}
```

now i want to sort Training based on `City name` . 
is there a way to do it in Grails (Gorm)way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
def results = Training.withCriteria {
    order('venue.city.name', 'asc')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Training.list().sort{it.venue.city.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def results = Training.list(sort:"venue.city.name", order:"asc")
```